# Django form templates: How to check if a field is optional?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a simple form, view and template file as described below.
One of my form field is required (url1) and one is optional (comment1).
In my template, I would like to display that field tags for these two fields differently based on if they are optional or not (for example: Required in red, Optionali in green). How can I do that?

Ideally there would be a boolean value in the form that looked like this: form.url1.required_flag

Here is my form:

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    url1 = forms.URLField(max_length=255, label='URL #1', required=True)
    comment1 = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label='Comment #1', required=False)
```

The view for this form is very simple. Nothing fancy.

Here is the relevant part of the template file:

```
<tr>
    <td width="100" align="right">
        <div class="field_label">
            {{ form.url1.label_tag }}:
        </div>    
    </td>
    <td width="300">
        <div class="form_element_input">
            {{ form.url1 }}
        </div>    
    </td>
    <td width="100" align="right">
        <div class="field_label">
            {{ form.comment1.label_tag }}:
        </div>    
    </td>
    <td width="300">
        <div class="form_element_input">
            {{ form.comment1 }}
        </div>    
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: why not put in the label "optional" or "required"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% if form.comment1.field.required %}
  //do something
{% else %}
  //do something else
{% endif %}
```

Should help

But again, you can pretty much use CSS to just color the comment with one color and url with another. I dont think you need to use required for that

Comment: Thanks. Solved. That's exactly what I needed.
I prefer using the required field so that my template is more generic. If I change the form field from required to optional, I want the HTML output to reflect that change without having to also change the template file. It's a form of the DRY philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `required_css_class`

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    required_css_class = 'required'
    url1 = forms.URLField(max_length=255, label='URL #1', required=True)
    comment1 = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label='Comment #1', required=False)
```

You can reach css classes with `form.field.css_classes` or they get printed out if you use any of `as_p`, `as_table` methods.